# Merging properties files using cucumber-spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-spring

We are using cucumber + selenium to facilitate e2e tests. We are using following dependencies to leverage on spring dependency injection.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then we configure spring context using these two classes

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringContextConfig.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}
```

```
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.example.e2e")
public class SpringContextConfig {
}
```

As we can se we properties source is defined explicitly pointing to a given file. **Is there a way to achieve the "magic" that Spring Boot does with profiles and properties files?**

For example I would expect spring when specifying `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` to merge
`application-dev.properties` with `application.properties` and giving the final context properties.

Answer (score 0):

> As we can se we properties source is defined explicitly pointing to a given file. Is there a way to achieve the "magic" that Spring Boot does with profiles and properties files?

[Profile specific configuration files are a Spring Boot feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-profile-specific). So if you are using Spring boot, this should be sufficient to have the active profile picked up:

```
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}
```

From your dependencies however it doesn't look like you are using Spring Boot. There is no other (easy) way to use profile specific configurations files. Consider making your application a Spring Boot application.